# Getting 1st index from SugarORM

Tags: java, android

on website SugarORM we can read

```
Note: Record indexes start at index 1.
```

and

```
Load Entity:
Book book = Book.findById(Book.class, 1);
```

But this 1 in Load Entity is a ID not index.
If i have 5 books in DB, and I Delete all, then add next 1 book, this new 1 book will be have  ID 6, and index 1, so:

how to delete by index not from ID column ?

Answer (score 0):

A not-very-good approach (as I don't believe there's a built-in way) would be to just do `listAll()` to get a standard Java list, then access the desired element using `.get()`.

Obviously this isn't a great way to do it, and would absolutely run into issues on large data sets, but for small tables it will work. Inefficiently.